# SignalR Example Application failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, websocket, signalr

I'm trying to follow steps over [here](https://sahansera.dev/understanding-websockets-with-aspnetcore-5/). When I try to run

```
let webSocket = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:5001/ws');
```

I run in console the followed, I get the error.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:5001/ws' failed: 
(anonymous) @ VM62:1
```

[image]

I simply created .Net 5 Web API and installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core` nuget package.
What is the point I miss? Could you help me? It is my first WebSocket approach.

Here is WebSocketsContoller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace LearningWebSocket.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WebSocketsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<WebSocketsController> _logger;

        public WebSocketsController(ILogger<WebSocketsController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet("/ws")]
        public async Task Get()
        {
            if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "WebSocket connection established");
                await Echo(webSocket);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            }
        }

        private async Task Echo(WebSocket webSocket)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
            var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Message received from Client");

            while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
            {
                var serverMsg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Server: Hello. You said: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)}");
                await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(serverMsg, 0, serverMsg.Length), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
                _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Message sent to Client");

                result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Message received from Client");

            }
            await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "WebSocket connection closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use this example: https://github.com/hgmauri/signalr-socket-dotnet5